# php throwing "undefined index" or not sending email in email form

Tags: php, html, forms, email, indexing

I am trying to put a basic email form on a website and have been having trouble with "unidentified index". I read around and found that "isset()" had solved this issue. I found that

```
$... = isset($_POST['...']);
```

does get rid of the error message, but my code does nothing. The page doesn't even refresh or throw another error. Here is my html:

```
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <h1>Send Us an Email</h1>
        <header class="emailbody">
           <label>Name</label>
           <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">
        </header>
        <section class="emailbody">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">
        </section>
        <footer class="emailbody">
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea><br>
        </footer>
        <div class="submitbutton">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
        </div>
    </form>
```

And here is my php:

```
<?php

    $name = isset($_POST['name']);
    $email = isset($_POST['email']);
    $message = isset($_POST['message']);
    $from = 'From: SiteDemo';
    $to = 'exemail@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Hello';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

?>
```

I have tried it with and without the "isset()" around the different indexes. Without, it throws an error and with, the code doesn't do anything.

Comment: do u want to send empty email??? if values are not set??

Answer (score 1):

Two things need to be corrected:

1) You have not written `mail()` function statement.

2) `isset()` returns only `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending upon whether variable is set or not. It does not return variable if variable is set.

Correct it to:

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
```

Same for other variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `isset()` here for checking either value set or not like that:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
   // if you dont want to send empty email.
   if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['message'])) 
   {
      $name = trim($_POST['name']);
      $email = trim($_POST['email']);
      $message = trim($_POST['message']);
      $header = "From: SiteDemo"; 
      $to = 'exemail@gmail.com';
      $subject = 'Hello';

      $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
      mail($to,$subject,$body,$header);
   }
}
```

And add name attribute in submit button as:

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send" name="submit">
```